# REST Basic Authentication not working

Tags: 7, services, authentication-authorization

I configured my rest with services and installed the Basic authentication module.
[image]

I used Postman and selected basic authentication gave username and password, I got "Missing required argument username"

[image: Postman]

An important note is that If I change it to "no Auth" and send my username and password as JSON object it's authenticating, can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, as the response says, 'username' name/key is missing from the request. So construct a body request like follows or else follow the screenshot

```
{"username":'myusername', "password":"mypassword"}
```

[image]

Comment: If I got to Body>Json and send the request (as JSON) it's working but it's working even If I put it in no auth...